# How can I get the text color of a button using the Substance LaF?

Tags: java, swing, substance

In my Java application I have to custom-paint a control and for that I need to use the same font colors as `JButton`. (Enabled and disabled) I don't want to hard-code them, because the user can change the Substance skin at runtime.

I'm aware of the `ColorSchemes` but I'm not sure how to proceed once I have the color scheme of the current skin. Also the Substance documentation says something about creating your own color scheme, but I just can't figure out the way to retrieve a certain color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally I figured it out myself:

The important step is to figure out the *correct* color scheme. Because in Substance every root pane can have its own skin, it's best to use the `getCurrentSkin`helper.

```
SubstanceColorScheme s = SubstanceLookAndFeel
        .getCurrentSkin(myComponent)
        .getEnabledColorScheme(
                SubstanceLookAndFeel.getDecorationType(myComponent)
         );
```

Other possibilities are `getDisabledColorScheme`, `getActiveColorScheme` and `getBackgroundColorScheme`.

Then you can use `s.getForegroundColor` or various helper methods from `SubstanceColorUtilities`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ask Kirill (creator of Substance) on Substance Forum at https://substance.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectForumView